# How to convert object values of pandas dataframe to number of hours?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
number_of_hrs  number_of_pts
65             1
7              1
31             1
6 DAY          1
23             1
21             1
5.0            1
```

I want to convert values like "6 DAY" to a number of hrs. is it possible?

Comment: that is possible, 6 DAY is 6*24=144 hours?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart how to write this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `.loc` and `str.extract`

using a regex pattern gives you a little more flexibility but ansev's `pd.eval` solution is slicker.

```
idx = df.loc[df['number_of_hrs'].str.contains('day',case=False)].index

pat = '(\d+)\s{1}DAY'

hrs = (df.loc[df['number_of_hrs'].str.contains('day',case=False)]["number_of_hrs"].str.extract(
    pat
).astype(int) * 24)[0]

df.loc[idx,'number_of_hrs'] = hrs
```

---

```
print(df)

  number_of_hrs  number_of_pts
0            65              1
1             7              1
2            31              1
3           144              1
4            23              1
5            21              1
6           5.0              1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) with [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

```
df['number_of_hrs'] = pd.eval(df['number_of_hrs'].str.replace('DAY','*24'))
print(df)
#  number_of_hrs  number_of_pts
#0            65              1
#1             7              1
#2            31              1
#3           144              1
#4            23              1
#5            21              1
#6             5              1
```

or

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['number_of_hrs'] = df['number_of_hrs'].str.replace('DAY','*24').apply(literal_eval)
#Alternative
#df['number_of_hrs'] = [literal_eval(s) for s in df['number_of_hrs'].str.replace('DAY','*24')]
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that, that is a timedelta, you can get the seconds equivalent and convert it hours as follows

```
df.loc[df['number_of_hrs'].str.lower().contains('day'), 'number_of_hrs'] = df['number_of_hrs'].seconds//3600
```

Comment: This gives in my case an error 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
```

The data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'number_of_hrs':[65,7,31,'6 DAY', 23,21,5.0], 'number of pts':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

The code:

```
df['number_of_hrs'] = pd.eval(df['number_of_hrs'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r' DAY', '*24', str(x))))
```